# Simple? 3D geometry question

Tags: geometry, 3d, angle

I want to grind a specific front angle on a piece of metal in the horizontal plane while at the same time having a specific secondary angle in the vertical plane.

If I present the workpiece at, for example, 45 degrees, dead flat to the grindstone (a flat plane 90 degrees to the horizontal) then a 45 degree angle is cut. If however, I then tilt the workpiece down by say a secondary angle (e.g. 30 degrees) I then need to tilt the workpiece in the horizontal by a further number of degrees to maintain the 45 degree primary angle.

If we call the primary angle X and the secondary angle Y, how does X vary with Y?

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide a (sketchy ...) figure in order that the question is non ambiguous. On this kind of issues, the asker understands perfectly well the situation whereas it is very very unclear for those who read the question.

Comment: I actually think the relationship is one to one.